# How to safely convert Hibernate hi/lo to pooled?

Tags: java, hibernate, sequence

Unfortunately, I started a project with

```
@Id
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "hibernate_sequence")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "hibernate_sequence",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
        parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "100"),
                @Parameter(name = "optimizer", value = "hilo")
        })
private Integer id;
```

before I learnt that there are better ways. The problem is that my hi/lo algorithm generates values which have to be multiplied by 100 before they get used. So while I see a sequence value like 1107 in the database, it means something like that values 110700 to 110799 will get used for the next ID. This makes adding entities manually pretty error-prone.

So I'd like to switch the algorithm to pooled or pooled-lo. For this I need to change the stored value to maybe 110800? Losing a few ID's obviously doesn't matter, but I'm asking as I need a fool-proof way.

A side question (admittedly, opinion-based): Should I go for pooled or pooled-io?

Comment: Vlad Mihalcea explains how: https://vladmihalcea.com/migrate-hilo-hibernate-pooled/

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the code of the [HiLoOptimizer.generate](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.10.Final/org/hibernate/id/enhanced/HiLoOptimizer.java#HiLoOptimizer.generate%28org.hibernate.id.enhanced.AccessCallback%29)

```java
@Override
public synchronized Serializable generate(AccessCallback callback) {
    final GenerationState generationState = locateGenerationState( callback.getTenantIdentifier() );

    if ( generationState.lastSourceValue == null ) {
        // first call, so initialize ourselves.  we need to read the database
        // value and set up the 'bucket' boundaries
        generationState.lastSourceValue = callback.getNextValue();
        while ( generationState.lastSourceValue.lt( 1 ) ) {
            generationState.lastSourceValue = callback.getNextValue();
        }
        // upperLimit defines the upper end of the bucket values
        generationState.upperLimit = generationState.lastSourceValue.copy().multiplyBy( incrementSize ).increment();
        // initialize value to the low end of the bucket
        generationState.value = generationState.upperLimit.copy().subtract( incrementSize );
    }
    else if ( ! generationState.upperLimit.gt( generationState.value ) ) {
        generationState.lastSourceValue = callback.getNextValue();
        generationState.upperLimit = generationState.lastSourceValue.copy().multiplyBy( incrementSize ).increment();
    }
    return generationState.value.makeValueThenIncrement();
}
```

on the very first run:

1. Current value from the DB is read (`lastSourceValue`). Note that callback is expected to update DB state automatically. For `SequenceStyleGenerator` this should be done by the DB-specific implementation of the sequence-like feature.
2. Code enusres that `lastSourceValue` >= 1
3. `upperLimit` = `incrementSize` * `lastSourceValue` + 1
4. `value` = `upperLimit` - `incrementSize`  = `incrementSize` * (`lastSourceValue` - 1) + 1. Code ensures that `lastSourceValue` >= 1 so that (`lastSourceValue` - 1) is still not negative and the `value` is at least 1
5. the `value` is returned as the first generated ID

So if the sequence in your DB stores 1234, then the first ID that is guaranteed to be unused yet (i.e. even not pre-pooled) is 123**3**01 = (1234 - 1) * 100 + 1.

***Pessimistic mode***: still all the maths and logic aside why not add `2 * increment_size` more just to be on the very safe side?